Can I use “can” here?
Does using “can” instead of “will be able to” in bold sound natural to native English speakers? I am wondering if “can” can express the meaning of future possibility.
Does this sentence in bold sound natural?

This is the only port still under our control. If the enemy occupies it in their next attack in December, they can cut off the supply line to our capital at the beginning of 2025.


Sounds normal to me. "could" would also be reasonable.

Thanks for replying @Barmar Are you a native speaker of American English?

yes, for 60+ years

The probability or remoteness of the action matters, and helps choose between can and could.

can there would have the practical meaning "there will be nothing to stop them from cutting the supply line."  It is stronger than mere possibility. There is a suggestion of likelihood. This putative "can" vs "will be able to" distinction has been a bugbear of usage mavens for more than a century.

This question is similar to: Can I use “can” here?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Considering "can" versus "will be able to"...
Each of the actions occurs at a different moment in time:

the next attack (in December)
cut off the supply line (beginning of 2025)

Therefore at the time of the attack, and even after it, the supply line remains intact.  The cutting will occur afterwards, at a later point in time.  This fact about the timing is elucidated and confirmed by the proper sounding phrase "will be able to", which is a good choice.
"Can" is not wrong, per se.  It's simplified. It sounds colloquial.  When somebody is speaking quickly and conversationally, they often use the simple present tense in place of other tenses (both past and future).
Therefore it matters if this is formal written communication or casual conversation.  That's a determining factor. I would suggest "will be able to" is the correct answer in most written formats while "can" is acceptable, especially in speech. Although, the more I think about it, the more I prefer "will be able to" for this particular case.

we can also use could. This sentence could means possibility.
will be able to capability or ability

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review

standard English for formal contexts:

This is the only port still under our control. If the enemy occupies it in their next attack in December, they will be able to cut off the supply line to our capital at the beginning of 2025.

If + present followed by a main clause in the future.
For example:
If he arrives late, that will disrupt our plans.
